# Python PYPI - I cannot upload my module cause the filename has already been used

Tags: python, pypi

### Problem

Im trying to pubblish my pypi python module but I runned into an problem where I can't upload it cause I get an error `HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ This filename has already been used, use a different version. See https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for more information.`  i think its happening  cause I tried uploading it earlier and something didn't work so I removed the project on pypi website and when I tried again the  error happened.

### What I tried

- Changing version - same error
- Removing project and uploading again - same error

Comment: https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse: "**PyPI does not allow for a filename to be reused, even once a project has been deleted and recreated.**"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are trying to do. It is not permitted. If you follow the provided link in the error message, it states:

> PyPI does not allow for a filename to be reused, even once a project has been deleted and recreated.

This is a common decision for package repositories (npm also has the same behaviour). The rationale behind it is to ensure data integrity. That is, once you have started using a given version of a package you will always get the exact same code for the given version. In the best case scenario, a user  of the package might be relying on behaviour that you now consider a bug. In the worst case scenario a person could delete a package+version and upload a new version with malicious code. So re-uploading a given package+version is not permitted.

If you have tried uploading a different version and it didn't work, then it means you uploaded a package with that version once before (and may have since deleted it).

If you are just trying to get to grips with the PyPI interface then it is recommended that you use the test PyPI instance. https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/